# FPDF calibri not showing euro sign

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, fpdf

I'm currently using FPDF to generate a PDF quote. I want to get the following output:

€ 520

by doing this:

```
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, chr(128).' 520', 1, 0);
```

But fpdf just shows an empty space. I am using Calibri as a font, and i load it doing this:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Calibri', '', 'calibri.php');
```

But to no avail. Funny enough, chr 123 to 127 and 129 etc work. The euro sign is the *only* sign not showing up. Anyone have a clue how to do this one?

**UPDATE:** when i try

```
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, utf8_decode('€ 520'), 1, 0);
```

i get a questionmark. It shouldn't be an invalid font, because I spotted chr(128) in calibri.php.

Answer (score 1):

I altered the calibri.php font by removing "128 /.notdef". Somehow it worked after that...

Answer (score 0):

try to use iconv

```
$euro = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', '€');
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, $euro.' 520'), 1, 0);
```

cp1252 (Western Europe) 
the header() in php not print in file pdf your request, but only in a page.

Comment: You should expand your answer to explain what you're doing and why it solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

this one is working too and can be used with strings that contain more than one €:

```
$this->Cell(140, 4, mb_convert_encoding($string, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8"), $border, 0, "L");
```

HTH

Comment: please try explaining what you have done and why it solves the asker's issue. it will be helpful to the next person stumbling upon your solution.